# What are the differences with Khet 2.0?

Tags: edition-comparison, khet

I believe I played the original Khet a few years ago, now I notice there is a "2.0 version". Could anyone point out the main differences?

Comment: I heard there is a beam splitter accessory for khet 1.0.  Is there something similar for khet 2.0 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [ThinkGeek](http://www.thinkgeek.com/geektoys/games/e739/):

> For those of you that loved the original Khet, you're gonna just flip
>   for Khet 2.0, but we'll sum up game
>   play for you who are new to the game.
>   In Khet 2.0 Laser Game, there are four
>   types of playing pieces, and two of
>   them have mirrors. Game play is
>   simple, and easy to learn, as there
>   are only a few movement choices. The
>   goal is to eliminate your opponent's
>   Pharaoh. And, you eliminate the
>   Pharaoh just like they did in olden
>   times - by firing a red laser! And
>   this is where Khet 2.0 kicks the game
>   up a notch.
>
> In the original Khet, the lasers were
>   part of the board. But in Khet 2.0,
>   the lasers are built in to special
>   Sphinx pieces that perch in the corner
>   and can now rotate to change the angle
>   of the beam (because of this change,
>   the board is very slim and now built
>   to travel)! Your laser is fired after
>   your turn and bounces from mirrored
>   piece to mirrored piece (always
>   shooting off at a 90 degree angle). If
>   the laser hits any piece on a
>   non-reflective surface (with one
>   exception we'll leave as a surprise),
>   that piece is removed from play. If
>   you eliminate your opponent's Pharaoh,
>   you win. If you eliminate your own
>   Pharaoh, you will be mocked for all
>   time (because it is possible). Khet
>   2.0 Laser Game is the next generation of the best laser game of all time.

So it seems that the form factor has changed, the lasers can be rotated, and there's a new piece added.

Comment: Doesn't moving the lasers increase complexity too much? Has anyone tried both?

Comment: The new lasers don't significantly change the complexity, as they don't *move* in a normal game.  The only rules change there is the ability to rotate 90 degrees to fire 'left'.